Using newBackgroundContext in @MainActor class
I have a class that fetches data from Firebase and caches it in Core Data.
import CoreData

import Firebase

@MainActor
class AccountStore: ObservableObject {
    private var context = CoreDataManager.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var accounts: [AccountModel] = []

    func fetchAccounts(user: User) async throws {
        let snapshot = try await db.collection("accounts")
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .getDocuments()

        try context.truncate(Account.self)

        let accounts = snapshot.documents.map { item -> AccountModel in
            let data = item.data()

            let account = Account(context: context)

            let model = AccountModel(
                id: item.documentID,
                uid: data["uid"] as! String,
                marketId: data["marketId"] as! String,
                name: data["name"] as! String,
                main: data["main"] as! Bool
            )

            account.model = model

            return model
        }

        try context.save()

        self.accounts = accounts
    }
}

In the View, I call the function inside .task:
.task {
    do {
        try await accountStore.fetchAccounts(user: user!)
    } catch {
        handleError(error: error)
    }
}

Is it right to use the background context inside a @MainActor class?
Does the function running inside .task mean it runs in the background, so is @MainActor significant in this case?
Is it better to pass the environment context @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context to the fetchAccounts function instead of creating a new background context?

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017
